# How to display random line from text file

Tags: java, random, text-files

```
for(int i=0;i<FullLineQues.length;i++){
    random.nextInt(i);
    Question=new String[6];
    Question=FullLineQues[i].split(",");                        
    commit=0;
    made=false;
    br=new BufferedReader(ir);
}
```

I want to random my line from text file, but it doesn't work

Comment: It's not really a good idea to initialize a BufferedReader in the way you are doing it here. Because you are initializing it again in every for loop you are losing a BufferedReader to memory every time you go through. Considering the BufferedReader is initialized with 'ir' that isn't set in the for loop it would be good practice to initialize it outside of the loop. Similarly, Question is being 'newed' every time through the loop. So, when you are setting Question equal to FullLineQues[i].split(",") you are losing that information every time through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea is to get a random index from 0 to the number of lines and then use it to retrieve this line.

```
int randomLineNumber = random.nextInt(numberOfLines);
```